# Flink - Run multiple flows in isolation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, production-environment

I am running multiple flows in flink. As of now they are written in single Main() method and they are running a single job. But, failure in one is affecting another and results in stopping the flink application. I want to run these flows in isolation.

Below are the flows -

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.fromSource(input1)
  .keyBy(...)
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink1)

env.fromSource(input2)
  .keyBy(...)
  .window(...)
  .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink2)

env.execute()
```

To run them in isolation what I did was -

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env1 = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamExecutionEnvironment env2 = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env1.fromSource(input1)
  .keyBy(...)
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink1);


env2.fromSource(input2)
  .keyBy(...)
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
  .sinkTo(sink2);
```

Does this will run it in isolation?
Also I read the article here - https://flink.apache.org/2020/07/14/application-deployment-in-flink-current-state-and-the-new-application-mode/

As shown in below diagram - when submitting multiple applications to job manager, it runs them in isolation. How can I achieve it?

- [image]